# Packaging an application with an OBDC connection

Tags: c#, installshield-le

i'm packaging an application using visual studio 2012 and install shield limited edition. during the setup i would need to make an obdc connection to a mysql database for the application to work. does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: What driver are you using?  Sql Server?  MySQL?  I found this: http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/InstallingMySQL-ODBCdriverMSI.htm

Comment: i'm using mysql. thanks a lot. i'll try this.